# Quantify group homogeneity

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity

I have a set of data which are responses to ten questions. 
I have done some text analysis which gave me 10 similarity matrices (one for each question) between all responses for each question.

I also have some demographic data on the respondents. I expect that some groups will respond more similarly than others. For example, people who have strong political leanings are likely to give similar answers to other people with the same political leanings, compared to those who are political indifferent, or lean the other way.

I want to quantify and test the within group homogeneity while controlling for various variables, like difference in age, or the question they are answering. I guess I am trying to model the group variances?

Is this possible?